# android activity can't recover

Tags: android, android-activity, recover

When I click my app's icon on the desktop,the splashactivity will first run, then it start the loginactivity before it finished. I click the loginbutton to login.then I came to the mainactivity.Then I click the HomeKey to goto the Android Home. At this time ,I click the app's icon again, the splashactivity start firstly. Why the mainactivity can't be recover? Othewirse,when I click the HomeKey at loginactivity ,the app can skip the splashactivity and recover the loginactivity.Thanks.

Comment: you need to go to login activity after the splash every time you launch the app?

Comment: No, I need the app go back to the state what before the HomeKey be Clicked .Thank you .

Comment: Make the ``LoginActivity`` your main activity, and only show the ``SplashActivity`` when you want to (i.e., once a day).  Ideally, you would want to show a splash screen while the program is loading in the background - although the common practice now adays is more about advertising the App than anything else.

Comment: Thank you.But after I make the **LoginActivity** as main activity,I also can't recove the **MainActivity** when I Click the HomeKey at the **MainActivity** and click the app's icon latter. I think if the MainActivity can't be keeped when it running background. How can I keep it aways running ?

Comment: @mrres1 Please post you comment as an answer and iterate over it further is the question can be worked with accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats very unusual, when a home key is pressed, an app is usually restored in the state it was left. At least thats what i have seen with all apps i have on my phone. What you could do is control your app flow using onPause() and onStop() as they get called when HomeKey is pressed.

Comment: Yes, I override the OnPause() method,but just like this ** protected void OnPause(){ super.OnPause(); BaseActivity.isMainPageRunnint = false; } ** I do the same at other Activity but this question never happened.

Comment: If you are running on ICS and above, did you check if u have ticked Settings -> Developer Options -> Dont keep Activities? The fact that the splash screen starts is because you activity is getting killed and there no recovery state for it, hence android starts it all over again

Comment: Thank you! I checked and the checkbox is not choiced. The other acitvity can recover just the **MainActivity** can't.

Comment: Thanks again,this happened because I make the **MainActivity** singleInstance .

Comment: Welcome, kindly accept the answer as right one, this might help others facing the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you create your `LoginActivity` as the launch activity, then you can display `SplashActivity` only when you want to display it.  My recommendation was being once a day.

In the `onStart` of your `LoginActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    /* 
        get last stored time & date of onStart using SharedPreferences
        get the current time & date

        if (current day != stored day)
            store date and time
            startActivity(SplashActvity)
    */
}
```